# How to redirect to a new component after creating a product

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to another component called `./productdetail`

I have tried using  provided by react router router.

```
    render() {
        const {redirect} = this.state;

        if(redirect){
            return <Redirect to='./productDetail' /> 
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    ... form content
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I expect to be redirected to the "./productdetail" component but it does not work like that. It still remains in the "./uploadproduct" component.

Comment: Never mind. I was updating state wrongly. fixed it with 
```this.setState({redirect:true})``` after ```axios``` returns ```response``` and it works.

Comment: Just curious, do you really put a "." before the route path? Does that actually work for you?

Comment: That was an oversight but it worked. Have corrected that.